# Using PowerShell to list Object Description

Tags: csv, active-directory, field-description

I have a CSV file with a list of PC's in my domain.  I wanted to get the "Description" Field information from AD for each of the machines listed in AD.  This is what I have so far:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*Server*"} -SearchBase "OU=Active,OU=Regular Computers,OU=EPComputers,DC=epenergy,DC=net" -Properties * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName | Export-Csv C:\PCList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I am not sure where I need to add in the get-ADObject and filter out the Description Field or even where to begin on that.  Any help would be awesome!

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently only outputting the following properties: Name,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName to your CVS. If you add Description to the list of objects your are selecting you should also get the Description properties too.

```
Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName,Description
```

this would make your block of code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*Server*"} -SearchBase "OU=Active,OU=Regular Computers,OU=EPComputers,DC=epenergy,DC=net" -Properties * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName,Description | Export-Csv C:\PCList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I did my testing using the following though, it returned the name, Description, OperatingSystem and CanonicalName of all of the machines on my domain:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Select-object name,Description,OperatingSystem,CanonicalName | Export-Csv C:\PCList.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You might find [this website](http://ss64.com/ps/get-adcomputer.html) useful, I can almost always find answers to my powershell questions on ss64